# Swift Firebase array

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Im trying to append Values from my JSON data above^ and put them into my array called values. I then need to retrieve those values in my updateChartValues() function and append them to a new array. What is the best way to do this in swift3?

When I try to append them in recieveChartValues() im not getting anything when I print the value.

1.) Append all key values in to array named values

2.) Make sure the values array full of data makes it to updateChartValues()

I need to:

1.)-fill the array from firebase

2.)-make sure array and values make it to the updateChartValues() function

3.) Make sure this loop iterates through array data

```
for i in 0 ..< values.count {
entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: UIImage(named: 
"icon", in: Bundle(for: self.classForCoder), compatibleWith: nil)))

        print("Value: ", values[i])

    }
```

project code

```
var values = [Double]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            var chart = LineChartView(frame: popUpView.frame)

            self.getFirebaseValues() { (bearishFloat, bullishFloat, xFloat) -> () in

            let totalCountY = self.chartMath(bearishFloat: bearishFloat, bullishFloat: bullishFloat)

            self.uploadChartIndexValues(totalCountY: totalCountY)

                self.dataSet = self.updateChartValues()

                self.setChartInterface(chart: chart, dataSet: self.dataSet)

            }

    }//End view Did load



 func updateChartValues() -> (LineChartDataSet) {

       self.recieveChartValues() //dont know if i should call this in viewDidLoad

        var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = Array()

        for i in 0 ..< values.count {

            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: UIImage(named: "icon", in: Bundle(for: self.classForCoder), compatibleWith: nil)))

            print("Value: ", values[i])

        }



        self.dataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: "Bullish vs. Bearish")
        self.dataSet.mode = LineChartDataSet.Mode.cubicBezier


        return dataSet

    }




func recieveChartValues() {

        //Firebase Initialization
        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("general_room_index").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in


            if let snapDict = snap.value as? [Double:AnyObject]{


                for each in snapDict{

                    print("key ", each.key)
                    self.values.append(each.key)
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: When you say you're "not getting anything" when you print the value, does that mean you don't even see the "key " string? Or that nothing follows the "key " string in the output? My guess is that you're suffering from type conversion issues (i.e., `snap.value` may not be `[Double:Anyobject]` but instead - by looking at your sample data - might be `[Int:Int]` or something else entirely.)

For diagnosis, try `print`-ing the raw `snap.value` before the assignment to `snapDict`. Alternatively, you could set a breakpoint and interrogate the types of `snapDict` and/or `snap.value`.

Answer (score 0):

Swift cant parse your `[Int: Int]` data from Firebase into `[Double: AnyObject]`.

Try to write:

```
if let snapDict = snap.value as? [Int: Int] {
```

instead of

```
if let snapDict = snap.value as? [Double: AnyObject] {
```

Hope it helps.